# Post Order by custom meta value date where format like dd-mm-yyyy is not working

Tags: wordpress

I have create a custom post type named circular where custom meta `circular_date` I need to display post order by meta_value return = 01/01/2020 (DD/MM/YYYY) this format

so I write query like:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$today = date('d/m/Y');
$circular_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'         =>'circular',
    'post_per_page'     => 20,
    'meta_key'          => 'circular_date',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value', 
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'paged'             => $paged,
    'meta_query'        => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'circular_date',//thay bằng meta key của bạn
                'value'   => date('j/n/Y'),
                'compare' => '>=',
                'type'    => 'DATE'
            ),
         ),

    ));
```

Comment: Dunno if it's just a typo but your date format "j/n/Y" should be "d/m/Y if you have leading zeroes

Comment: It would be much easier to save `circular_date` with format (YYYY/MM/DD).

Comment: but already saved (dd/mm/yyyy) format